# Присваивание input"file"-у файла через drag&drop

Tags: javascript

1) Как сделать так, что б когда мы перетягиваем файл в область дропа, этот файл присваивался инпуту (как будто мы выбрали его через инпут)? 
2)Как сделать так, что б картинка которую мы поместили в область дропа становилась бекграундом, этой области?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dropZone = $('#dropZone')
    // Проверка поддержки браузером
  if (typeof(window.FileReader) == 'undefined') {
    dropZone.text('Не поддерживается браузером!');
    dropZone.addClass('error');
  }
  // Добавляем класс hover при наведении
  dropZone[0].ondragover = function() {
    dropZone.addClass('hover');
    return false;
  };
  // Убираем класс hover
  dropZone[0].ondragleave = function() {
    dropZone.removeClass('hover');
    return false;
  };
  // Обрабатываем событие Drop
  dropZone[0].ondrop = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    dropZone.removeClass('hover');
    dropZone.addClass('drop');
    var file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
    document.getElementById("file").files[0] = file;

  };
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px Arial, sans-serif;
}
#dropZone {
  color: #555;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#dropZone.hover {
  background: #ddd;
  border-color: #aaa;
}
#dropZone.error {
  background: #faa;
  border-color: #f00;
}
#dropZone.drop {
  background: #afa;
  border-color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<form action="/upload.php">
  <div id="dropZone">
    Для загрузки, перетащите файл сюда.
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="file" id="file" multiple>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы были очень близки к решению.
Необходимо изменить следующий участок кода.

```
 document.getElementById("file").files = event.dataTransfer.files;
```

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/jy843h26/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dropZone = $('#dropZone')
    // Проверка поддержки браузером
  if (typeof(window.FileReader) == 'undefined') {
    dropZone.text('Не поддерживается браузером!');
    dropZone.addClass('error');
  }
  // Добавляем класс hover при наведении
  dropZone[0].ondragover = function() {
    dropZone.addClass('hover');
    return false;
  };
  // Убираем класс hover
  dropZone[0].ondragleave = function() {
    dropZone.removeClass('hover');
    return false;
  };
  // Обрабатываем событие Drop
  dropZone[0].ondrop = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    dropZone.removeClass('hover');
    dropZone.addClass('drop');
    document.getElementById("file").files = event.dataTransfer.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < event.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
      var file = event.dataTransfer.files.item(i);
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        // browser completed reading file - display it
        // console.log($('#imagePreview'),e.target.result);
        var $img = $('<img>');
        $img.attr('src', e.target.result);
        $('#imageContent').append($img);
      };
    }

  };
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px Arial, sans-serif;
}
#dropZone {
  color: #555;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#dropZone.hover {
  background: #ddd;
  border-color: #aaa;
}
#dropZone.error {
  background: #faa;
  border-color: #f00;
}
#dropZone.drop {
  background: #afa;
  border-color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/upload.php">
  <div id="dropZone">
    Для загрузки, перетащите файл сюда.
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="file" id="file" multiple>
  <div id="imageContent">

  </div>
</form>
```